# infinite subset of discrete metric space is not compact

Tags: discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, self-learning, compactness

The question is

[image]

Im not really sure how to go about this

So far i am trying to show that for an open cover of the infinite subset X, there isn't a finite sub cover and therefore X is not compact

I am not really sure how to show this properly.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be "trying to show that for an open cover of the infinite subset $X$, there isn't a finite subcover"; rather you should be trying to show that for each infinite set $X$ of points **there is at least one** open cover of $X$ that has no finite subcover.  The *negation* of the statement $\text{“}$For **every** open cover blahblahblah$\text{''}$ is the statement $\text{“}$For **at least one** open cover, **not** blahblahblah.$\text{''}$

For each point in $X$, you can find an open neighborhood of that point that contains no other point of the space; hence no other point of $X$.  That's where you use the fact that the space is discrete.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove:
Let $(X,d)$ is a discrete metric space. If $A\subseteq X$ is compact then $A$ is finite.

Since $A$ is compact, you can cover it with balls of radius $\frac{1}{2}$. So, you may obtain a finite sub cover of this set. But, in a discrete metric space, open balls of radius $<1$ are singletons. Hence $A$ is finite.