# Infinite metric space with discrete metric is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> Consider the metric space $(X, d)$, where $d$ is the discrete metric; let $K$ be an infinite subset of $X$. Show that $K$ is not compact in $(X, d)$.

To show $K$ is not compact, I've done this:

Since $K$ is an infinite subset of $X$, it follows $K$ is an infinite discrete metric space. Consider $G = $ {{$k$} | $k \in K$}, which is an open cover of $K$. Clearly, $G$ has no finite subcover. Thus, $K$ is not compact.

How does my proof look? Do I need to explicitly show why $G$ has no finite subcover? Thank you.

Comment: That looks fine. Maybe mention $G$ has no finite subcover because $K$ is infinite? But that's not that important.

Comment: Correct, the singleton sets are open sets and so with a cover of singlwton sets, there is obviously no finite subcover for $K$

Comment: I was wandering if we're able to show the statement using *sequential compactness*, since the situation is settled in a metric space (where open-cover-compactness and sequential compactness are the same)? How does a sequence in $K$ without any convergent subsequence look like?

Comment: @ComplexFlo If you want to use sequential compactness, take $N\subseteq K$ such that $|N|=\aleph_0$ ($K$ is infinite). Take an enumeration $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to N$ of $N$ (in fact, a sequence). Recall that a sequence in a discrete space is convergent if and only if is eventually constant. Every subsequence of $\phi$ is not eventually constant, thus, doesn't converge.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [infinite subset of discrete metric space is not compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608150/infinite-subset-of-discrete-metric-space-is-not-compact)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can prove this with sequences too.

Since your metric space is infinite, you can extract a countable set $\{a_{1}, \dots, a_{n}, \dots\}$ (with distinct points), thus 
$$
d(a_{i}, a_{j}) = 1
$$
for all $a_{i}, a_{j}$ (with $i \neq j$). This means that this sequence can't have any Cauchy subsequence.

An additional note - to someone who doesn't have much experience with compactness or the discrete metric - try to think of why this proof fails in a finite set. (Hint: can you extract a constant subsequence from every sequence with only finitely many distinct values?)

Answer (score 0):

Any $H\subset G$ is equal to $\{\{x\}: x\in S_H\}$ for some $S_H\subset X.$ And $H$ is finite iff $S_H$ is finite. So if $H$ is a finite subset of $G$ then $\cup H=S_H \ne X$ because $S_H$ is finite while $X$ is infinite.